# Implications of converting a Visual Studio 2005 solution to 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I have an existing Visual Studio 2005 project for which I get a conversion wizard prompt when opening in the freshly installed Visual Studio 2010. What are the implications of carrying out this conversion? Converting to anything more recent than 2010 is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion process is usually pretty seamless, it will take your 2005 project and upgrade it to a 2010 project.

It *should not be an issue* unless you have projects with 3rd party components which, for whatever reason, do not like the newer version of Visual Studio. The only one I've ever had a problem with is Crystal Reports and that was going from a .NET 1.1 project in VS2003 to .NET 4.0 in VS2010. (But hey, one does not simply do things with Crystal Reports)

The conversion wizard will also back up your old project if you tell it to, although I would hope it's in source control of some kind anyway.

Of course, people who *only* have VS2005 on their machine will no longer be able to open your upgraded 2010 project, you are effectively committing to VS2010. It can always later be upgraded to VS201x at a later date if this becomes an option.